# NPM Error Parsing Json, Unexpected Token

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I'm trying to install grunt, but no luck.

```
npm install -g grunt-cli --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

gives this error:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli" "--registry" "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! Unexpected token <
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
npm ERR! <html><head>
npm ERR! <title>404 Not Found</title>
npm ERR! </head><body>
npm ERR! <h1>Not Found</h1>
npm ERR! <p>The requested URL /grunt-cli was not found on this server.</p>
npm ERR! </body></html>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Any reason you're trying to specify the registry?  Did you try just `npm install -g grunt-cli`?  From the body, it looks like it can't find `grunt-cli` on that server.

Comment: @Brennan I did try that. it gives me this error "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED"

Comment: That's odd.  I just did it and it works for me.  Do you have an `.npmrc` or something that would change your default registry?  You may also try using `--registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` (note the `https`).

Comment: @Brennan I'm sorry, but I'm actually not sure what .npmrc is. Could that be the problem? Tried https, gave me this error "tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED" "in most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings."

Comment: An `.npmrc` is a file that you can set defaults for the `npm` tool to use.  It doesn't look like that's the issue.  Are you behind some firewall or proxy as the message suggests?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This did it for me, although not sure why.

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.ch/2013/11/set-and-reset-proxy-for-git-and-npm.html

Comment: @TylerChong `rm -f package-lock.json && npm install`

Answer (score 29):

I just ran the command,

### first:

`$ rm -f package-lock.json`

### after:

`$ npm i`

work for me ;)

Comment: Yup, just deleted the package-lock.json file and everything starting working again.