# Angular Issue: npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<html> npm ERR! <head> npm ERR! <title...'

Tags: angular

Tried both the solution from the below mentioned answer:

[NPM Error Parsing Json, Unexpected Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810614/npm-error-parsing-json-unexpected-token)

1) SOLUTION 1:

```
$ rm -f package-lock.json

after:
$ npm i
```

In this case , my app does not contain package-lock.json to remove.

2)SOLUTION 2:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

It was already set and I could able install all other dependencies. So,i don't think,the problem occur in this case.

Tried `npm cache clean --force` as well. Doesn't work.

May i know why does it fail.

Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: try ```npm cache clean --force``` then```npm install -g @angular/cli```

Comment: Have you tried removing `node_modules` folder and then doing `npm install` ?

Comment: It works after deleting the node module and install npm ..Thanks @SaddamPojee

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `node_modules` folder and then run `npm install` command